# TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined (line 3, file "Code")

Tags: ios, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been following a post on reddit explaining how to edit a google spreadsheet via an apple shortcut on your phone. I have followed everything correctly and I still always receive the following error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined (line 3, file "Code") . Here is the link for the post on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/j2m7wd/a_shortcut_guide_ios_to_track_expenses_and_check/

The code used is within that post on reddit but I will also include it here:

```
var financesheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetid").getSheetByName('Sheet1');

function doGet(e) {
  var amount = JSON.parse(e.parameters.amount)
  var account = JSON.parse(e.parameters.account)
  var category = JSON.parse(e.parameters.category)
  var detail = JSON.parse(e.parameters.detail)
  var formattedTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "h:mm a");
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  financesheet.appendRow([formattedDate, +amount, account, category, detail]);
}
```

Can anyone help me determine what I'm doing wrong? Also I am very very much a beginner when it comes to this kind of stuff so I may need a little more step by step then normal. Thank you!

Comment: Basicly it is telling you that `e.parameters` is undefined. So I dont know what you are trying to send in `e`. But if I would be I would initiate all your `var` from JSON with default parameters, and then test if `e.parameters` is defined to set possible value

Comment: How have you publish/deployed your webapp?